# method gettext(); dont get all he newlines when the caretUpdate Event

Tags: position, listener, caret, jtextcomponent

hi i'm trying to make a method to get the exact position of the caret in a JTextComponent similar as the getMagicCaretPosition(), but when I type only newline the method gettext(); doesn't get all the newlines that I have in my component

when i used to use  getMagicCaretPosition() and also a ChangeListener, it doesn't work as well when i move the caret to the bottom or top in a empty newline, that's the reason now i'm trying to make my own method

this my CaretListener:

```
    if(OBJETO instanceof JTextComponent){

                JTextComponent objetotexto=(JTextComponent)OBJETO;
                objetotexto.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
                    int pointx=0,pointy=0;
                    @Override
                    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
                        JTextComponent tempo=((JTextComponent)e.getSource());
                        if(tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition()!=null){
                            //here replace the "\n" for ".__._..__:.__..-_...-__." because
                            //when i made the split the "\n" was lost
                            String aaaa=tempo.getText().substring(0, tempo.getCaret().getDot()).replaceAll("\n", ".__._..__:.__..-_...-__.");
                            System.out.println(aaaa.split(".__._..__:.__..-_...-__.").length+" must be the conut of newlines");
                            String te[]=aaaa.split("\\p{Space}");
                            for (int i = 0; i < te.length; i++) {
                                te[i]+=" ";
                            }
                            int aux=0;
                            int enter=1;
                            for (int i = 0; i < te.length; i++) {
                                aux+=AnchoContenido(te[i], tempo.getFont());
                                if(aux>=AREAVISIBLE.getWidth()){enter++;aux=AnchoContenido(te[i], tempo.getFont());}
                                if(te[i].indexOf(".__._..__:.__..-_...-__.")>=0){enter+=te[i].split(".__._..__:.__..-_...-__.").length;aux=0;}
                            } 
                            //this result supposed to be the pointy
                            System.out.println((enter*tempo.getFontMetrics(tempo.getFont()).getHeight()));
                            pointy=(enter*tempo.getFontMetrics(tempo.getFont()).getHeight());
                            pointx=(pointx<tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().x)?tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().x+50:tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().x-50;
                            ColocarPuntoVista(pointx,pointy);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

public int AnchoContenido(String texto, Font formato){

        return new JLabel().getFontMetrics(formato).stringWidth(((texto.equals("")?" ":texto)));
    }
```

this is my old code:

```
if(OBJETO instanceof JTextComponent){

            JTextComponent objetotexto=(JTextComponent)OBJETO;
            objetotexto.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
                int pointx=0,pointy=0;
                @Override
                public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
                    JTextComponent tempo=((JTextComponent)e.getSource());
                    if(tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition()!=null){

                        pointx=(pointx<tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().x)?tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().x+50:tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().x-50;
                        pointy=(pointy<tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().y)?tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().y:tempo.getCaret().getMagicCaretPosition().y;
                        ColocarPuntoVista(pointx,pointy);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

this is a perspective of I want
[image]

I need the exact position of the carect

Thanks for  your advices and answers, i'm not very well with english sorry for my way to write